# changing script to jquery combining another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I put together, which a button is clicked it rotates 45 degrees, I also would like it to toggle a paragraph open and closed.  I don't have access to the CSS because the content management system interwoven wont' let me have accerss, so this is why it's all done with the javascript and it has to stay that way.  The script is:

```
var img = document.images[0];
effects_of_yoga_info.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out");


var deg = 0;
effects_of_yoga_info.addEventListener('click', function() {
deg += 45;
effects_of_yoga_info.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+deg+'deg)');
```

and the part I'd like to incorporate into it so that they happen at the same time is:

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_info").click(function () {
  $("p#effects_of_yoga_text").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

I'm sure it's very simple but I've been having a hard time with it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
$(img).click(function () {

    deg += 45;
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ(' + deg + 'deg)');

    $('#KittenText').slideToggle("fast");

});​
```

Comment: well i'd like it to still animate, I have part of it set up here with teh image that rotates, but don't know how to write it as jquery so teh css is incorporated the same way as well as include the paragraph toggle. http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/SZXyj/

Comment: wow I'm really sorry, I entered the first script wrong, just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

got it working:

```
var img = document.images[0];
effects_of_yoga_info.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out");


var deg = 0;
effects_of_yoga_info.addEventListener('click', function() {
$("p#effects_of_yoga_text").slideToggle("fast");
deg += 45;
effects_of_yoga_info.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+deg+'deg)');   
});
```